# Undo/Redo или CTRL+Z – CTRL+Y »» не работает для личных макросов

Tags: excel, vba

Есть макросы по теме ··· заливка; цвет текста; вставить примечание. Для них не работает Undo/Redo (которые расположены на QAT) ни <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> – <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>.
Нашёл вот такие ссылки [wellsr.com](https://wellsr.com/vba/2019/excel/how-to-undo-a-macro-with-vba-onundo-and-onrepeat/#comment-4551766283) и [jkp-ads.com](https://jkp-ads.com/Articles/UndoWithVBA04.asp) там есть инфа, правда не понятно как это всё скомбинировать с моими всеми макросами!?

---

Пример XML+VBA реализация книги [тут](https://yadi.sk/d/unc1wimztVtLRg) (макрос заливка цвета).
Один юзер предложил рабочий вариант! Вот только досадно то что у меня заливок для цвета много скажем 30-40. Как это всё адаптировать, мож переменную какую то вставить на место `xSelection.Interior.Color` :

Заметьте что это готовый рабочий вариант Undo/Redo! ↴↴↴ ↴↴↴ ↴↴↴

```
Sub CellColor()
Call CellColor_Do(0)
End Sub
 
Private Sub CellColor_Do(Undo As Integer)
Static xBook As Workbook, xSheet As Worksheet, xSelection As Range, xColor As Long
Const sName As String = "CellColor"
Const sUndo As String = "Undo Color in "
Const sRedo As String = "Redo Color in "
If Undo = 0 Then
    Set xBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set xSheet = ActiveSheet
    Set xSelection = Selection
    xColor = Selection.Cells(1).Interior.Color
    xSelection.Show
    xSelection.Interior.Color = RGB(227, 38, 54)
    Application.OnUndo (sUndo + xSelection.Address(False, False)), (ThisWorkbook.Name + "!" + sName + "_Undo")
ElseIf xSelection Is Nothing Then
    Beep
Else
    xBook.Activate
    xSheet.Activate
    xSelection.Select
    xSelection.Show
    If Undo < 0 Then
        xSelection.Interior.Color = xColor
        Application.OnRepeat (sRedo + xSelection.Address(False, False)), (ThisWorkbook.Name + "!" + sName + "_Redo")
    Else
        xSelection.Interior.Color = RGB(227, 38, 54)
        Set xSelection = Nothing
    End If
End If
End Sub
 
Private Sub CellColor_Undo()
    Call CellColor_Do(-1)
End Sub
 
Private Sub CellColor_Redo()
    Call CellColor_Do(1)
End Sub
```

Есть ещё макрос к которому тоже хочу прикрутить:

```
Sub Note_FillColor_White()
Dim myComm As Comment
  If Not ActiveCell.Comment Is Nothing Then
    If MsgBox("Ячейка уже содержит примечание, удалить?", 4) - 7 Then
      ActiveCell.Comment.Delete
    Else: Exit Sub
    End If
  End If
 
Set myComm = ActiveCell.AddComment
    With myComm.Shape
      .Height = 110
      .Width = 200
      .Top = 55
      .AutoShapeType = 1             'форма
      .Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 1 'заливка » Белый
      .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      .DrawingObject.Font.Name = "Consolas"
      .DrawingObject.Font.FontStyle = "normal"
      .DrawingObject.Font.Size = 8
     End With
      'Эмулируем выбор пункта "Изменить `Заметку`"
       SendKeys "+{F2}"
End Sub
```

Ещё макрос (нужна прикрутка):

```
Sub CoverCommentIndicator(control As IRibbonControl)
    'www.contextures.com/xlcomments03.html
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cmt As Comment
    Dim lCmt As Long
    Dim rngCmt As Range
    Dim shpCmt As Shape
    Dim shpW As Double 'ширина формы
    Dim shpH As Double 'высота формы
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    shpW = 8
    shpH = 6
    lCmt = 1
    
    For Each cmt In ws.Comments
      Set rngCmt = cmt.Parent
      With rngCmt
        Set shpCmt = ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, _
          rngCmt.Offset(0, 1).Left - shpW, .Top, shpW, shpH)
      End With
      With shpCmt
        .Name = "CmtNum" & .Name
        With .Fill
          .ForeColor.SchemeColor = 9 'Цвет заливки
          .Visible = msoTrue
          .Solid
        End With
        With .Line
          .Visible = msoTrue
          .ForeColor.SchemeColor = 64 'Цвет обводки, задаётся автоматически для всех индикаторов!
          .Weight = 0.25 'Толщина обводки, задаётся автоматически для всех индикаторов!
        End With
        With .TextFrame
          .Characters.Text = lCmt
          .Characters.Font.Size = 5 'Размер текста
          .Characters.Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
          .MarginLeft = 0#
          .MarginRight = 0#
          .MarginTop = 0#
          .MarginBottom = 0#
          .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter 'Расположение текста (в данном случае в центре).
        End With
        .Top = .Top + 0.001 'Расположение рамки (в данном случае справа).
      End With
      lCmt = lCmt + 1
    Next cmt
End Sub
```

На самом деле макросов то у меня много (возможно если понять как прикрутить Undo/Redo к этим макросам - то можно будет понять формулу и в дальнейшем самому адаптировать).

Answer (score 0):

Утро доброе Россияне! 
По этому вопросу есть [тема](https://www.excel-vba.ru/chto-umeet-excel/kak-otmenit-dejstviya-makrosa/).

Первый макрос на мой взгляд самый подходящий. Заметил минусы:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> - не робит.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> - только на 1 шаг. А ещё стирает ячейку (то есть полоски/обводка самой ячейки)!
3. Если заливать несколько ячеек (мультиселект) - заливка не чёрная а разная у каждой ячейки (чёрная только первая). Ещё ячейки нумеруются 1, 2, 3 и т. д. (чтобы это значило)!?
4. Второй вариант вобще не торт, квас какой то.
5. @Сергей - кста, поделился хорошей [идеей](https://www.excel-vba.ru/chto-umeet-excel/kak-otmenit-dejstviya-makrosa/#comment-5618)!

   > Нужно создавать скрытый лист для надстройки и на нём хранить диапозон, имя листа, имя книги и имя процедуры, делавшая изменения.
   >   И когда нужно будет, отменять эти действия от конца, а в случае закрытия файла надстройки - очищать лист истории.

---

Есть какие идеи как это всё накатать на VBA?

Выше макрос которым я поделился оказался лучше (в шапке эттой темы, первый код, назван `Sub CellColor`)... Имеются те же нюансы а из плюсов:
Мультизаливка работает как надо. Нет никакой нумерации.

---

Наткнулся на вот такую надстройку [Ablebits](https://www.ablebits.com/downloads/index.php) называеься, (пробный период если то с оф. сайта качать ну а ещё всегда есть кряк [тут](http://cwer.ws/node/465560/) и [тута](https://diakov.net/11558-ablebits-ultimate-suite-for-microsoft-excel-2018311975836-business-edition.html)). Имеется свой бэкап Книги:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я им писал - (они там косят под американцев но я то знаю что там русские сидят) тоже говорят что у них нет доступа к каким то внутренним ресурсам Excel и поэтому реализовали для своих личных макросов такой BackUP. Используя кнопки в этой надстройке, заметил что <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> где то робит где то нет. Не смотря на то что смастерили драконскую надстройку а <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> реализовать не получилось.

Ещё на БУРЖ ресурсе прочитал такое:

> Фактически, запуск макроса полностью стирает список отмены, и поэтому вы не можете автоматически отменить эффекты запуска макроса. Нет встроенной команды в Excel или в VBA для сохранения списка отмены.

Есть у кого какие идеи по реализации вот таких вариантов бэкапа:

1. Описанный @Сергей -ем.
2. Ablebits бэкап.
3. Ну или пользоваться стандартным методом, а это - <kbd>DELETE</kbd>; удаление чего либо посредством "Context Menu"; Всегда делать копию Книги для отката.